# Copy files from a directory to another one with date in a specified range

Tags: date, batch-file, copy, range

As you can see in the object i need to copy all the files that have in the file name a date in a specified range.

I'll try to explain better with an example.

I have in a directory these files:

- 20140619_LogStat.txt
- 20140620_LogStat.txt
- 20140621_LogStat.txt
- 20140622_LogStat.txt
- 20140623_LogStat.txt
- 20140624_LogStat.txt
- 20140625_LogStat.txt
- 20140627_LogStat.txt
- 20140628_LogStat.txt
- 20140629_LogStat.txt
- 20140630_LogStat.txt

I need a batch file that ask me the starting date and the last date of the files to be copied in another one directory.

My code is:

```
@echo off

set /p StartDate= Inserire la data di INIZIO dei log da spostare (formato: AAAAMMDD)
set /p LastDate= Inserire la data di FINE dei log da spostare (formato: AAAAMMDD)

set /a Range=%LastDate%-%StartDate%

PAUSE

FOR %%A IN (1, 1, %Range%) DO (

set /a j=%StartDate% + 1

copy /-y "C:\%j%*.txt" "D:\directory"

)
```

This line ask me the starting date:

```
set /p StartDate= Inserire la data di INIZIO dei log da spostare (formato: AAAAMMDD)
```

This line ask me the ending date (as you can see in both line I've written the format requested):

```
set /p StartDate= Inserire la data di INIZIO dei log da spostare (formato: AAAAMMDD)
```

Then I set a Range so the number of days useful to the FOR CYCLE:

```
set /a Range=%LastDate%-%StartDate%
```

Now I need to repeat the FOR CYCLE in reference of the Range variable.
Then I set a new variable "j" that will be equal to (StartDate+1) first cycle, (StardDate+2) second cycle... and so on...

SO .. if my input (first two lines of code) is:
20140619
20140625

It does:
20140625-20140619=6 -> Range variable

The for cycle begin with 0 and continue to 6.

Set the variable 20140619+0 and copy the file 20140619*.txt to the directory

End of the FOR CYCLE and continue to sum 1 until the last file copied is 20140625 because 20140619+6=j is 20140625

I hope that my goal is clear.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the file format that you specified, this should work:

```
@echo off

set /p StartDate= Inserire la data di INIZIO dei log da spostare (formato: AAAAMMDD)
set /p LastDate= Inserire la data di FINE dei log da spostare (formato: AAAAMMDD)

FOR /L %%A IN (%startdate%, 1, %lastdate%) DO (
   if exist "C:\%%A_logstat.txt" copy /-y "C:\%%A_logstat.txt" "D:\directory"
)
pause
```

Comment: Realy thank you. It works perfect for me!!!
The range is not necessary because of I can define the start and the end in the for cycle. =)
Thanks agains!!

Comment: Thanks.  I will just comment that this does a numeric check and not a date compare.  It works because your date format is suitable, and the `if exist` command stops any errors occurring when it looks for a date like `20140698`

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

set /p StartDate= Inserire la data di INIZIO dei log da spostare (formato: AAAAMMDD)
set /p LastDate= Inserire la data di FINE dei log da spostare (formato: AAAAMMDD)


set "source_dir=c:\date_files\"
set "destination_dir=d:\directory"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%A IN (c:\date_files\*_LogStat.txt) DO (

        set "filename=%%~nA"
        set "file_date=!filename:~0,8!"

        if !file_date! GTR !StartDate! if !file_date! LSS !LastDate! (
            copy /-y "%%~fA" "%destination_dir%"
        )


)
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks to you too!
I've chosen the foxdrive solution because it's easier to be explaind!!
If I could I chosed both of you!!